# Matplotlib - draw a non-uniform line distribution

Tags: python, matplotlib

Consider the following matplotlib example: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/recipes/fill_between_alpha.html

With `fill_between` it can show a standard deviation:

```
ax.fill_between(t, mu1+sigma1, mu1-sigma1, facecolor='blue', alpha=0.5)
```

However, the area is filled uniformly, while the actual distribution is normal for each x-coordinate (I think). Is it possible to fill the area to reflect it (so that the color is the denser the closer the point is to `mu1`).

You can assume that I have arrays `mean` and `std`, which define a normal distribution for each x-coordinate, and I want to draw these distributions: `alpha` should be proportional to density.

As a solution, I can probably use several layers of `fill_between`, but it's not precise and is very hacky.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you could use a [filled contour](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.contourf.html?highlight=contourf#matplotlib.axes.Axes.contourf) with `X,Y,Z` data created with [np.meshgrid](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html) and [norm.pdf](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.norm.html).
I removed the `fill_between`'s in the [fill between example](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/recipes/fill_between_alpha.html) and added the following:

```
import matplotlib.cm as cm
from scipy.stats import norm

width = 2.0
YS = np.linspace(np.min(mu1 - sigma1 * width),
                 np.max(mu1 + sigma1 * width), 101)

X,Y = np.meshgrid(t,YS)
Z = np.zeros_like(X, dtype=np.float)
for i, (mu,sigma) in enumerate(zip(mu1,sigma1)):
    Z[:,i] = norm.pdf(YS, loc=mu, scale=sigma) * sigma

plt.contourf(X,Y,Z, cmap=cm.BuGn, levels=100)
```

This results in:
[image]

This does not use *alpha* yet, so it is only useful for one line, probably you can use *alpha* with customized colormaps, but this is trickier.